# Installation problems with distribute 0.6.26 on Python 3.2.3

Tags: python, setuptools, distribute, attributeerror

Working on a Windows 7 Python 3.2.3 implement and went to install something that required setuptools. Got distribute 0.6.26 instead due to version compatibility issues. But when I go to install it, I get the following errors:

```
File "C:\Python32\distribute_setup.py", line 494, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "C:\Python32\distribute_setup.py", line 489, in main
tarball = download_setuptools()
File "C:\Python32\distribute_setup.py", line 192, in download_setuptools
log.warn("Downloading %s", url)
File "C:\Python32\lib\distutils\log.py", line 47, in warn
self._log(WARN, msg, args)
File "C:\Python32\lib\distutils\log.py", line 30, in _log
if stream.errors == 'strict':
AttributeError: errors
```

There's probably something fundamental that I'm doing wrong. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there are problems with Distribute and 3.2.3. Found a site that had some unofficial forked installers that worked fine with 3.2.3. Here it is: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/